# How do i install .deb files on Ubuntu 16.04? I have tried anything

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, gdebi

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a bootable USB. I have been trying for days to install .deb files (AirVPN, Eddie version 2.11 found at "https://airvpn.org/linux/" the experimental version) and have tried many methods and browsed many forums but nothing has worked yet. I tried using the default Ubuntu Software app to install it, but after clicking the install button nothing happens.

I tried using the GDebi installer to install the .deb files but i couldn't find it on the Ubuntu Software application, and when I tried using terminal to install it, terminal gave me this error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gedbi-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gedbi-core
```

I also wasn't able to find out how to install the Gnome Installer.

It might be important to add that am new to Linux and this forum site, so my thread might be a little unorganized and i am not too experienced with the terminal (i catch onto things fast though so I'm not hopeless).

Comment: Typo? `gedbi` instead of `gdebi`?

Comment: What happens when you double click the Deb file?

Answer (score 4):

You can install using the `dpkg` command, for example:

```
sudo dpkg -i path/to/file.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct commands to install `gdebi` using the terminal app are:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core gdebi
```

Then find your .deb file to install, right-click on it and select properties, then select the `Open With` tab, then select `gdebi`, then click the `Make Default` button.

Then just double-click on your .deb files to install them!

Answer (score 0):

You got the spelling wrong it should be `gdebi` not `gedebi` so just simply try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

That should do it.

Comment: No it shouldn't `gedbi-core` doesn't exist. It's `gdebi-core`.

Comment: Including that the OP spelled the package wrong would help too.